# Javascript - Mouse Wheel Go to Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent, mousewheel

Every time I use the **mouse wheel** (you know normal scrolling) I want the JS (jquery or whatever) to scroll to a **specific class** (or id doesn't matter).

I have multiple divs so code like `$('body').scrollTo($nextdiv)` is not an option.

I just want to make every wheel cycle to move to a next div with a specific class/id. The same for the reverse scroll. To move one div (with a specific class) up.

I found mouse wheel event and how to move to a specific div but can't manage to make it work together.

Animated scroll would be cool.

Simple question. Can I have class AND id in the same div? ex `<div class="a" id="b">` ?

Comment: Yes, of course you can have `id` and `class`! Why not? You can even have multiple classes.

Comment: You can have a `class` and `id` in the same element. However, each `id` should only be used for one element

Comment: Thank you. I know about IDs but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following plugins: [jquery.mousewheel](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel) and [jquery.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) plugin, like:

```js
/*!
 * jQuery Mousewheel 3.1.13
 *
 * Copyright 2015 jQuery Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 */
!function(a){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],a):"object"==typeof exports?module.exports=a:a(jQuery)}(function(a){function b(b){var g=b||window.event,h=i.call(arguments,1),j=0,l=0,m=0,n=0,o=0,p=0;if(b=a.event.fix(g),b.type="mousewheel","detail"in g&&(m=-1*g.detail),"wheelDelta"in g&&(m=g.wheelDelta),"wheelDeltaY"in g&&(m=g.wheelDeltaY),"wheelDeltaX"in g&&(l=-1*g.wheelDeltaX),"axis"in g&&g.axis===g.HORIZONTAL_AXIS&&(l=-1*m,m=0),j=0===m?l:m,"deltaY"in g&&(m=-1*g.deltaY,j=m),"deltaX"in g&&(l=g.deltaX,0===m&&(j=-1*l)),0!==m||0!==l){if(1===g.deltaMode){var q=a.data(this,"mousewheel-line-height");j*=q,m*=q,l*=q}else if(2===g.deltaMode){var r=a.data(this,"mousewheel-page-height");j*=r,m*=r,l*=r}if(n=Math.max(Math.abs(m),Math.abs(l)),(!f||f>n)&&(f=n,d(g,n)&&(f/=40)),d(g,n)&&(j/=40,l/=40,m/=40),j=Math[j>=1?"floor":"ceil"](j/f),l=Math[l>=1?"floor":"ceil"](l/f),m=Math[m>=1?"floor":"ceil"](m/f),k.settings.normalizeOffset&&this.getBoundingClientRect){var s=this.getBoundingClientRect();o=b.clientX-s.left,p=b.clientY-s.top}return b.deltaX=l,b.deltaY=m,b.deltaFactor=f,b.offsetX=o,b.offsetY=p,b.deltaMode=0,h.unshift(b,j,l,m),e&&clearTimeout(e),e=setTimeout(c,200),(a.event.dispatch||a.event.handle).apply(this,h)}}function c(){f=null}function d(a,b){return k.settings.adjustOldDeltas&&"mousewheel"===a.type&&b%120===0}var e,f,g=["wheel","mousewheel","DOMMouseScroll","MozMousePixelScroll"],h="onwheel"in document||document.documentMode>=9?["wheel"]:["mousewheel","DomMouseScroll","MozMousePixelScroll"],i=Array.prototype.slice;if(a.event.fixHooks)for(var j=g.length;j;)a.event.fixHooks[g[--j]]=a.event.mouseHooks;var k=a.event.special.mousewheel={version:"3.1.12",setup:function(){if(this.addEventListener)for(var c=h.length;c;)this.addEventListener(h[--c],b,!1);else this.onmousewheel=b;a.data(this,"mousewheel-line-height",k.getLineHeight(this)),a.data(this,"mousewheel-page-height",k.getPageHeight(this))},teardown:function(){if(this.removeEventListener)for(var c=h.length;c;)this.removeEventListener(h[--c],b,!1);else this.onmousewheel=null;a.removeData(this,"mousewheel-line-height"),a.removeData(this,"mousewheel-page-height")},getLineHeight:function(b){var c=a(b),d=c["offsetParent"in a.fn?"offsetParent":"parent"]();return d.length||(d=a("body")),parseInt(d.css("fontSize"),10)||parseInt(c.css("fontSize"),10)||16},getPageHeight:function(b){return a(b).height()},settings:{adjustOldDeltas:!0,normalizeOffset:!0}};a.fn.extend({mousewheel:function(a){return a?this.bind("mousewheel",a):this.trigger("mousewheel")},unmousewheel:function(a){return this.unbind("mousewheel",a)}})});

// The actual code:
$(document).ready(function () {

var targets = $('.scroll'); // List of elements to scroll to
var index = 0;
var duration = 500;
var canScroll = true;
var cache;

function limit(x, min, max) {
 return Math.min(max, Math.max(min, x));
}

$(window).mousewheel(function (ev) {
 
 if (canScroll) {
  
  cache = index;
  
  if (ev.deltaY < 0) {
   index = index + 1; // Scrolling down, so increase index
  } else {
   index = index - 1; // Scrolling up, so decrease index
  }
 
  // Make sure the index is between 0 and (targets.length - 1)
  index = limit(index, 0, targets.length - 1);
  
  console.log(index);
   
  // Make sure to scroll if and only if the value has changed
  if (index !== cache) {
  
  // Scroll to the target element:
  $(window).scrollTo(targets.get(index), {
    duration: duration,
   easing: 'swing'
  });

  canScroll = false;
  setTimeout(function () {
   canScroll = true;
  }, duration);
 }
}
  
ev.preventDefault();
return false;
});
});
```

```css
div {
    content: ' ';
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #d0d0d0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.scrollto/2.1.0/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>

<div class="scroll">div1</div>
<div class="scroll">div2</div>
<div class="scroll">div3</div>
<div class="scroll">div4</div>
<div class="scroll">div5</div>
<div class="scroll">div6</div>
```

Comment: Will this work for any div? I want to the it to scroll down to multiple divs. Like class="div1" class="div2"  class="div3". So every time I scroll it will go to the next div with the same class name.

Comment: Yes, see the edit. You could use the modulo operator to make it start over again.

Comment: It would be better to use IDs instead of classes here: use `#div` instead of `.div` and use classes and IDs on the element together.

Comment: Ok. I will try it. What about the reverse scroll? I want ti go one div up.

Comment: Then you would use `--i` instead of `++i`. Or maybe somewhat more obvious: `i -= 1` instead of `i += 1`.

Comment: @user1947700 I would use the [`wheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) event instead of the `scroll` event for that: use an argument in the function: `function(e)` and in the function body, test whether e.deltaY is positive or negative. If you want more compatibility, you’d have to do it with a comparison of `window.scrollY` between two states.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? I added scrollTo.js to my website. Added "div1" "div2" etc to the divs I want it to scroll, but nothing happens. Any help?

Comment: I've adjusted the code and added a working code snippet.

Comment: Look like it what I need but it doesn't work on my local server.
I added the css, copied the body. In header placed "HTTP:" so scripts can be loaded. Created a file mousewheel.js and added it to the website. Doesn't work. But code snipped here works fine.

Comment: Copied all the scripts to local directory. Even downloaded jquery 1.11.3 and added to the website. Did it 4 times. Not working on my local server. STRANGE. Your code snippet is working fine.

Comment: @user1947700  Press F12 on Chrome and check the error messages after running local website.

Comment: The page is loading well, no errors. But every time I scroll the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined" appears. The problem is in jquery.scrollTo.min.js:7.

Note: It worked when I got the code **directly** from code snippet. The strange thing... the code inside <script> works. When I call it from src (same exactly code) it won't. Just don't work. I would use this code but it's too long, too messy. It must be plain without external file.

Comment: @user1947700 That error occurs because the jQuery selector `$('.scroller')` returns a empty list, which means that it can't find any elements with the class attribute `scroller`. You might want to wrap the code in a DOM ready event handler or put the code snippet before the closing `body` tag.

Comment: I'm a bit lost right now. What is the easiest way to fix it? And are you sure it's "scroller" and not "scroll"? Thank you for your time.

Comment: You're right. It is `scroll`. The easiest way to fix it: check that there are elements with the class attribute `scroll`, wrap the code in a DOM ready event handler (I've updated the script with that handler).

Comment: It works but behaves strangely. The problem is that it start scrolling before the last scrolled is finished. If the user scrolled 3 times it will go 3 divs down and it's very confusing before the user will understand how the scrolls work. So I want ti do ignore the scrolling if the screen is still animating. I would also need the script to stop when it reach the bottom (same for the top). Thank you. I really don't understand how the code is working PERFECTLY fine in the code snippet and not on my machine and server (any browser).

Comment: Maybe changing the sensitivity of mouse wheel will resolve this problem. Maybe putting a single wheel scroll to be equivalent to three scrolls. Thanks.

Comment: @user1947700 I've solved both your problems by adding a `canScroll` boolean variable in combination with a time-out. Also the `modulo` function is replaced by a `limit` function which limits the current index to larger than or equal to zero and less than the total number of elements. If this is what you seek, you should accept this answer. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Works great BUT... The scroll on IE and CHROME looks like crazy when scrolling. And when the page is most bottom (no more to scroll) and there are still divs it thinks that is scrolled and when you scroll up you have to scroll those divs without the actual page being scrolled. So, it looks like the page froze and not going up until you scrolled enough. Try it so you can understand better my issue.
I will choose your question as the answer anyway but if you can fix those two issues I would be very happy :D Thanks again.

Comment: Is there a way to make this script to "understand" when the scrollbar is not moving and reached the bottom?
As for the "crazy" scroll bar, if I'm not wrong, with the previous code it worked pretty well.

Comment: I'm testing the code in other page not in the code snippet you provided. Just a page with some text and titles (divs with scroll class).

Comment: @user1947700 Can you send me the code? Or replicate the issue in jsfiddle?

Comment: How do I send a private message?

Comment: Theere is no way so, ok here is the link:
http://www71.zippyshare.com/v/j1eAZIb7/file.html

Comment: @user1947700 Ok, now I see the problem. I've updated the code which provides a fix for the problem. Note that if the `.scroll` elements are larger, you will observe a difference scrolling the last elements down.

Comment: Works great. Thank you. Any way to fix the problem with the last item? I can just remove the scroll class from the last two divs if there is no easy way to fix it.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, use this function from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/488073/1717562. You only have to change `if (index !== cache)` to `if (index !== cache && !isScrolledIntoView(targets.get(index)))`. If this solutions fits your requirements you could accept the answer.

Comment: It's not really works. It also skips some divs when scrolling down. But works fine when scrolling up. I found a piece of code which send an alert/message when a scrollbar reaches the bottom. Maybe replacing the alert(""); with a variable with a certain number will make it work. (maybe setting the canScroll to false will work or decreasing the index).

Answer (score 0):

Quick example, this code can be improved. Better to test on jsfiddle. Point mouse over list and scroll.

Note: I didn't use class but if you understand what I did it's easy to use classes.

Note 2: I just change color but logic can be replace with anything you want.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/91ko9Lb0/)

[demo 2 (with classes)](https://jsfiddle.net/91ko9Lb0/5/)

```js
var i = 0;

var list = document.getElementById("list"), length = list.children.length;
list.addEventListener("wheel", ColorLi);

function ColorLi(e) {
    //reset colors
    for(var j = 0; j < length; j++)
        list.children[j].style.color = "black";
    //calculate index
    if(e.wheelDelta > 0)
        i++;
    else
        i--;
    //fix index out of range
    i = i < 0 ? 0 : i;
    i = i > length-1 ? length-1 : i;
    //set color
    list.children[i].style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li style="color: red">A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's not working on jsfiddle. Am I doing something wrong again? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @user1947700 move your move on letter A and the move mouse wheel up or down

Comment: Tried. Not working. Nothing happens at all. Am I stupid or something? I clicked on your demo, changed no option. Went to the Result panel. Tried the wheel. Nothing happens. Any help?

Comment: Tried Chrome. Works fine (just inverted controls). Not working on Firefox 40.0

Comment: @user1947700 what browser you using? Also look demo 2 with classes.

Comment: I want it to be compatible on "all" browsers. At least ie >7 and general desktop browsers. I will optimize it for mobile later.